# Unable to show success or error message in Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working in Next JS, and I am trying to use an API via Axios, the API is working fine but is unable to display any **message** (success or failure) on the web page. In my console, it's showing **success** but not displayed on the web.

Here is my code:

```
const subscribeMe = async (event) => {
            const emails = email;
            event.preventDefault();
            const res = await fetch('https://myurl.com/admin-panel/Api/subscribe?email='+emails);
            const { error, message } = await res.json();
            if (error) {
                    console.log('error);
                    setError(error);
            } else {
                    console.log('two');
                    setSuccess(message);
            }
};
```

To display the **Success** or **Error** message I am using the following code (after submitting the button of the newsletter form). Where am I going wrong?

```
{success 
? 
<span className="flex items-center text-sm font-bold text-green-700"> 
{success}
</span> 
: 
<span className="flex items-center text-sm font-bold text-red-800">
{error} 
</span>
```

Here is my whole component code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Subscribe = () => {
 const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
 const [error, setError] = useState('');
 const [success, setSuccess] = useState('');

const subscribeMe = async (event) => {
            
            console.log('data is '+email);  
            const emails = email;
            console.log('emails id is '+emails);    
            
            event.preventDefault();
            
            const res = await fetch('https://myurl.com/admin-panel/Api/subscribe?email='+emails);
            //const success ="Om Success";


            const { error, message } = await res.json();
            if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    setError(error);
            } else {
                    console.log(message);
                    setSuccess(message);
            }
};
    const changeEmail = (event) => {
        const email = event.target.value;
        setEmail(email);
    }
   return (
    
                <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-lg-7 ft-img">
                  <img src="img/xchanger.png" />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-lg-5 ft-form">
                  <form className="row g-3" onSubmit={subscribeMe}>
                    <div className="col-12">
             

            <input type="subscribe" className="form-control" id="subscribe2" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Please Subscribe" onChange={changeEmail}
              />

              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mb-3">subscribe</button>
              </div>

                    {success 
                       ? 
                    <span className="flex items-center text-sm font-bold text-green-700"> 
                        
                         {success}
                    </span> 
                       : 
                    <span className="flex items-center text-sm font-bold text-red-800">
                    
                          {error} 
                    </span>
                }

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     
   )
}
export default Subscribe
```

Comment: Where have you set the success variable ? Is it after fetch  call ?

Comment: @subodhkalika: as i said i am new in nextjs, maybe i set variable after fetch call ( as showin in code , after await fetch

Comment: Have you tried logging the values of  `sucesss` and `error` variables?

Comment: @Khalil: sorry but not understand your point sir

Comment: Try `console.log(error)` and `console.log(success)`

Comment: @Khalil: i tried sir but nothing is showing

Comment: Can you share the code of the whole component?

Comment: @Khalil: sure sir, going to update my question ( going to share whole component code)

Comment: @Khalil: updated my question sir, you can check my code

Comment: Everything seems fine to me. Can you `console.log()` the value returned by `await res.json()`;

Comment: Hey @Amit, have you tried debugging it? I have provided a link in my answer with some more information on how to debug it with Chrome DevTools... if you are not familiar with debugging, that's a great opportunity to learn it and start relying on that (instead of relying only on console.logs) :) I'm sure it's going to be a helpful skill (know how to debug) for you in this problem as well in other future scenarios. all the best

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is related to next.js...

I think you should add a `try/catch` block within `subscribeMe` and debug it by adding a `debugger` to better understand what's going on

```
const subscribeMe = async (event) => {
  try{ 
    debugger;

    // ---- your `subscribeMe` code ---- 

    console.log('data is '+email);  
    const emails = email;
    console.log('emails id is '+emails);    
    
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const res = await fetch('https://myurl.com/admin-panel/Api/subscribe?email='+emails);

    const { error, message } = await res.json();
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setError(error);
    } else {
      console.log(message);
      setSuccess(message);
    }
    // ---- your `subscribeMe` code ---- 
    
  } catch(error) {
    debugger;
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Open [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/) (or similar inspection feature in other browser) and check what's going on!

I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

The code ran fine when I tried it. I would say to check your css.

Comment: sir i am not using tailwind i am using bootstrap

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Amit i edited my answer. But my best guess would still be something css related.